# How to define Rails route for a HEAD request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-6

I just started getting errors in my logs:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [HEAD] "/auth/cas"
```

There is most definitely a route for "/auth/cas" (although it's buried in a gem) but *not for a HEAD request*.  These errors coincide with UptimeRobot.com hitting my server, but it appears that they just started using HEAD requests, because I wasn't getting these when I originally set up my account with them.

Since I can't change the way UptimeRobot works, and I don't want to find a different service, how can I create a route that will handle this request or otherwise make it go away?

There's nothing in the Rails routing guide about how to handle HEAD requests.

Comment: Just use another route / URL for uptime monitoring. One that's under your control and not "buried in a gem".

Comment: The uptime monitor is being redirected to an authentication page, and (apparently) instead of GETting it, it is first HEADing it.  All URLs require authentication.  I wanted to create a "heartbeat" page that didn't require authentication but the powers that be decided that wasn't worth my time—even though you and I know it's very little time, it just SOUNDED like too much work to them, and they want FEATURES DAMMIT—so I'm looking for a faster solution.

Answer (score 1):

Rails does not have a built in `head` [routing helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/HttpHelpers.html). But you can define a route that maches any HTTP method imaginable with the  [`match` method](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match) that they use under the cover:

```
match "/auth/cas", to: "foos#bar", via: :head
```

Comment: Adding `head` and `options` would make a nice PR though.